# llamada de procedimiento almacenado sin parámetros desde c#

Tags: c#, sql-server

Buen día, espero que estén bien el día de hoy.
Quisiera sacarme una duda, es que debo de ejecutar un procedimiento almacenado sin parámetros desde C#, ya que el programa que estoy haciendo debe de ejecutarlo.

```
  public void llamadaProcedure()
    {
        try
        {
            String procedimiento = "InsertarDatosTransferencia";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = procedimiento;
            cmd.Connection = conectarBD;
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            Trace.WriteLine("Procedimiento Exitoso");
        }
        catch (Exception eo)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine("Error en el procedimiento falló" + eo);
        }

    }
```

Obviamente ya está configurada la conexión, etc...
Lo que pasa es que no me está ejecutando el procedimiento almacenado, no me sale si tiene error, y el mensaje de éxito que puse en la consola realmente no me dice nada, no se si falta alguna línea para ejecutar o si de lo contrario se hace otra forma.

código del procedimiento almacenado.

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertarDatosTransferencia]
 @id nvarchar(20), @hora nvarchar(20), @puerta nvarchar(20), @idTarjeta nvarchar(4), @usuario nvarchar(100), 
 @departamento nvarchar(30), @idDep nvarchar(20), @nit nvarchar(20), @mensaje nvarchar(200), 
 @tarjeta nvarchar(30),@fecha date
 AS
DROP TABLE TEMPORAL_IV;
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TEMPORAL_IV](
    [id_temp_dia] INT NULL,
    [hora_temp] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [puerta_temp] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [id_tar_temp] INT NULL,
    [usuario_temp] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [desc_dep_temp] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [id_dep_temp] [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    [doc_usu_temp] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [mensaje_temp] [nvarchar](80) NULL,
    [num_tar_us_temp] [nvarchar](30) NULL) 
BULK INSERT TEMPORAL_IV from '\\argos\informatica$\temp\datos.csv' with (fieldterminator=';',FIRSTROW=2, ROWTERMINATOR='\r');
ALTER TABLE TEMPORAL_IV ADD fecha_temp date;

--UPDATE TEMPORAL_IV SET fecha_temp = DATEADD(DAY,-1,GETDATE()); ESTA LINEA ES PARA AGREGAR EL DIA ANTERIOR DE LA FECHA ACTUAL
UPDATE TEMPORAL_IV SET fecha_temp = GETDATE();



declare idat cursor for select id_temp_dia, hora_temp, puerta_temp, id_tar_temp, usuario_temp, desc_dep_temp, id_dep_temp, doc_usu_temp,
mensaje_temp, num_tar_us_temp, fecha_temp FROM TEMPORAL_IV;

OPEN idat
FETCH NEXT FROM idat INTO @id, @hora, @puerta, @idTarjeta, @usuario, @departamento, @idDep, @nit, @mensaje, @tarjeta, @fecha
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
BEGIN 
IF @id = (select id_trans_dia from TRANSFERENCIAS_IV WHERE fecha_trans =@fecha and id_trans_dia = @id ) 
 UPDATE TRANSFERENCIAS_IV SET id_trans_dia=@id, hora_trans=@hora,puerta_trans=@puerta,id_tar_trans=@idTarjeta,usuario_trans=@usuario,
    desc_dep_trans=@departamento, id_dep_trans=@idDep,doc_usu_trans=@nit,mensaje_trans=@mensaje,num_tar_us_trans=@tarjeta,fecha_trans=@fecha
    WHERE id_trans_dia = @id and fecha_trans = @fecha;
ELSE
 INSERT INTO TRANSFERENCIAS_IV (id_trans_dia,hora_trans,puerta_trans,id_tar_trans,usuario_trans,desc_dep_trans,id_dep_trans,doc_usu_trans,mensaje_trans,num_tar_us_trans,fecha_trans)
 VALUES (@id,@hora,@puerta,@idTarjeta,@usuario,@departamento,@idDep,@nit,@mensaje,@tarjeta,@fecha);
FETCH NEXT FROM idat INTO @id,@hora,@puerta,@idTarjeta,@usuario,@departamento,@idDep,@nit,@mensaje,@tarjeta,@fecha
END
CLOSE idat
DEALLOCATE idat
```

Comment: Tu procedimiento almacenado tiene parámetros obligatorios, por lo que no lo puedes llamar sin parámetros.

Comment: Gracias, no me habia dado de cuenta que había que colocar los parametros opcionales, así los instancié las variables:  `@id INT=null, @hora nvarchar(20)=null, @puerta nvarchar(20)=null, @idTarjeta INT=null, @usuario nvarchar(100)=null, 
 @departamento nvarchar(30)=null, @idDep nvarchar(20)=null, @nit nvarchar(20)=null, @mensaje nvarchar(200)=null, 
 @tarjeta nvarchar(30)=null,@fecha date=null` Y de hecho,, ejecutandolo en SQLserver si funciona, pero si lo llamo desde la aplicación sigue sin funcionar.

Answer (score 2):

Disculpen, solo faltaba una linea, y además los parámetros del procedimiento estaban obligatorios, así que lo primero era declarar los parametros como opcionales:

```
@id int=null,@hora nvarchar(20)=null,...
```

Y en el método de C# Para ejecutar el procedimiento almacenado solo faltaba una línea:

```
public void llamadaProcedure()
    {
        try
        {
            String procedimiento = "InsertarDatosTransferencia";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = procedimiento;
            cmd.Connection = conectarBD;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Trace.WriteLine("Procedimiento Exitoso");
        }
        catch (Exception eo)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine("Error en el procedimiento falló" + eo);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Hola Yerson Hernandez Posada: Te voy a poner un par de comentarios para ayudarte con tú código. No deberías de usar un sqlCommand y no cerrarlo. La mejor manera es encerrarlo en un Using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand()){ } y entre las llaves todo tú código. Asi, no tienes que cerrar la conexión y te liberan los recursos sin hacer nada.

Comment: En el procedure, estás utilizando la tabla Temporal_IV como una tabla propia de la base de datos, y no como una tabla temporal. Si el objetivo es usar una tabla temporal tienes que añadirle un # por delante. En varias sentencias utilizas fecha_temp, pero es una columna que no has definido en el create Table dbo.Temporal_IV.

Comment: Los cursores no son una buena política en lógica de conjuntos por muchos motivos. Puedes pensar en utilizar una sentencia Merge y quitar el cursor, la update y el insert. En este artículo puedes ver como se aplica: https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2019/10/04/merge-upsert-insertar-o-actualizar-en-una-sola-sentencia/